# git-credential-osxkeychain - broken credentials on my Macbook

Tags: git, bash, shell, terminal, keychain

I have multiple users on my Macbook running High Sierra (personal/work) and have been screwing around with my `.bash_profile` and `homebrew` settings on my "work" user for a certain issue, which I was able to resolve.

Unfortunately, when switched back over to my personal user, my git credentials keychain seems to have broken.

When I attempt to push or pull from my Github, I get the following error from git.

`cannot exec 'git-credential-osxkeychain': Permission denied`

I am prompted to enter my Username and Password every time I push or pull from the remote, which is tedious.

My `.gitconfig` looks like this:

```
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[user]
    name = yev
    email = yev@internet.website
[color]
    ui = true
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

I also attempted to add the following to my `.profile` file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$(git --exec-path)
```

This did not help.

Does anyone know where `git-credential-osxkeychain` is or is supposed to be located and/or how to restore these credentials.

Comment: On my Mac, `/usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain` is a symbolic link to the one installed by `brew install`. If you have several different versions of Git installed, they may be competing with each other for a single path. There are a lot of ways to handle this, each with its own set of drawbacks. I just try to avoid the situation if possible.

Comment: Where did you find the instruction telling you to set `credential.helper=osxkeychain`? That same documentation should tell you how to install the software required.

Comment: Update: I went ahead and did a brew upgrade (from git 2.13 to 2.15.1), which removed the `/usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain` symlink. Now there are just the two `Cellar` entries in `/usr/local`, one for 2.13.1 and one for 2.15.1_1.  However, `git credential-osxkeychain` still Just Works.

Comment: updating git and overwriting the symink worked! thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, updating git with homebrew and overwriting the symlink resolved it.

`brew install git`

`brew link --force git`

`brew link --overwrite git`

After restarting the terminal, keychain was restored!